# error states Unable to require(node_modules/prisma/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node) while npx performing prisma generate

Tags: node.js, orm, openssl, hadoop-yarn, prisma

I have a node.js project with prisma as ORM that connects to postgresdb. After I installed dependencies with `yarn install` I tried to run command `npx prisma generate` then I got error stating
*Unable to require(/node_modules/prisma/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node) libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*.

## local setup

I have ubuntu 22.04 with node version of v16.14.2.

Answer (score 5):

It seems there is an issue with the version of OpenSSL installed on your machine.
You might need to (re)install OpenSSL.

I suggest you [create an issue on prisma/prisma](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new/choose)

We have a few issues about this [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues?q=label%3A%22topic%3A%20openssl%22%20) and the solution is often specific to the configuration.

Comment: I tried changing my base container image from node-18:slim (which uses debian bookworm) and after a deeper check turns out it doesn't have openssl installed, changing base image to alpine solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add an option of `binaryTargets` in generator block in your `schema.prisma` file as mentioned in [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#linux-ubuntu).

Adding `debian-openssl-1.1.x` to your generator should solve your issue.

```
generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["debian-openssl-1.1.x"]
}
```

Comment: This should not be needed, though.
The error already shows that the correct engine is downloaded: "libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node"